# Create variables base on cURL response - Bash

Tags: bash, curl

I'm trying to create 2 variables via bash `$lat`, `$long` base on the result of my curl response.

> curl ipinfo.io/33.62.137.111 | grep "loc" | awk '{print $2}'

I got.

> "42.6334,-71.3162",

I'm trying to get

- $lat=`42.6334`
- $long=`-71.3162`

Can someone give me a little push ?

Comment: Pro tip - you can request ipinfo.io/33.62.137.111/loc to just get the coordinates, which simplifies some of the existing answers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```sh
IFS=, read -r lat long < <(
  curl -s ipinfo.io/33.62.137.111 |
    jq -r '.loc'
)

printf 'Latitude is: %s\nLongitude is: %s\n' "$lat" "$long"
```

The ipinfo.io API is returning JSON data, so let parse it with `jq`:

Here is the JSON as returned by the query from your sample:

```
{
  "ip": "33.62.137.111",
  "city": "Columbus",
  "region": "Ohio",
  "country": "US",
  "loc": "39.9690,-83.0114",
  "postal": "43218",
  "timezone": "America/New_York",
  "readme": "https://ipinfo.io/missingauth"
}
```

We are going to JSON query the `loc` entry from the main root object `.`.

- `curl -s ipinfo.io/33.62.137.111`: download the JSON data `-s` silently without progress.
- `jq -r '.loc'`: Process JSON data, query the `loc` entry of the main object and `-r` output raw string.
- `IFS=, read -r lat long < <(`: Sets the **I**nternal **F**ield **S**eparator to `,` and read both `lat` and `long` variables from the following command group output stream.

Comment: Wow, that's impressive answer. ✨

Comment: What is `jq` ? and why we need `< <` ? What is the first one do vs. the second one ?

Comment: `jq` is a `json` parser `<(` is called `process substitution` which is specific to `bash` afaik.

Comment: Oh it is a package where I have to install. I will install now.

Comment: What is the `.` in front `.loc` does ?

Comment: `jq` is a JSON parser with own query syntax (with extensive capabilities). `.loc` query `.` the root JSON object's `loc` entry. `< command_group_1 <(command_group_2)` redirect the output of `command_group_2` as the input of `command_group_1`. The first command group runs in the main thread and is allowed to access/write your shell variables while the second command group runs in a sub-shell.

Comment: Thank-you @LéaGris for your comments and answer. I hope you don't mind, help me out on a similar post, I asked here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61003685/create-many-variables-base-on-curl-response-bash

Answer (score 1):

Although the answer from @LeaGris is quite interesting, if you don't want to use an external library or something, you can try this:

Playground: https://repl.it/repls/ThoughtfulImpressiveComputer

```sh
coordinates=($(curl ipinfo.io/33.62.137.111 | sed 's/ //g' | grep -P '(?<=\"loc\":").*?(?=\")' -o | tr ',' ' '))

echo "${coordinates[@]}"

echo ${coordinates[0]}
echo ${coordinates[1]}
```

Example output:

```sh
39.9690 -83.0114 # echo "${coordinates[@]}"
39.9690 # ${coordinates[0]}
-83.0114 # ${coordinates[1]}
```

Explanation:

1. `curl ...` get the JSON data
2. `sed 's/ //g'` remove all spaces
3. `grep -P ... -o`

   - `-P` interpret the given pattern as a perl regexp
   - `(?<=\"loc\":").*?(?=\")`

     - `(?<=\"loc\":")` regex lookbehind
     - `.*?` capture the longitude and latitude part with non-greedy search
     - `(?=\")` regex lookahead
   - `-o` get only the matching part which'ld be e.g. *39.9690,-83.0114*
4. `tr ',' ' '` replace `,` with space
5. Finally we got something like this: `39.9690 -83.0114`

Putting it in parentheses lets us create an array with two values in it (cf. `${coordinates[...]}`).

Comment: If you want to avoid parsing with `jq` you can extract with `sed`: `read -r lat long < <(curl -s ipinfo.io/33.62.137.111 | sed -n 's/.*\"loc\"[[:space:]]*:[[:space:]]*\"\([[:digit:].]\+\),\([[:digit:].]\+\)\".*/\1 \2/p')`

Comment: @LéaGris that looks also good! But you can't be sure that let's say a *space* will follow right after the "loc" key, in-between or after the ":" etc., so I wanted to make sure that the parsing is kinda flexible.

Comment: This is why the `*` (0 or more) amount of spaces. They are optional per the JSON syntax.

Comment: Yes, my apologies. I just noticed that. Thanks.

Comment: @LéaGris one more little thing though, a digit can also start with a minus, which you can also add to the regex, no big deal. It just makes things less readable for me though - matter of taste.

Comment: Anyway, it is very hard to properly parse JSON syntax with a RegEx, even my example has remaining failure cases like if the key and value are on different lines or if the JSON string uses Unicode notations or whatever the already verbose RegEx can't replace a true JSON parser.

Comment: That's why I like JavaScript a lot. It has a wonderful built-in JSON parser. :D